# subprocess returns a "file not found" error whenever I try to run anything using it

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

the code is simply just

```
import os
import subprocess
os.system("dir")
subprocess.run("dir")
```

, but when subprocess gets called, it returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

. So how do I fix this?
(full error log)

```
PS C:\Users\...\> & C:/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/.../errorfixing.py
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is CCCE-1A39

 Directory of C:\Users\...\

03/03/2024  12:45    <DIR>          .
03/03/2024  12:45    <DIR>          ..
03/03/2024  15:50                69 errorfixing.py
03/03/2024  15:47             4,486 main.py
03/03/2024  12:20    <DIR>          media
03/03/2024  15:33                22 other.py
03/03/2024  11:46                35 other.txt
03/03/2024  14:54                62 other2.py
03/03/2024  15:32                11 stdout.txt
               6 File(s)          4,685 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  49,271,283,712 bytes free
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\errorfixing.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.run("dir")
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Look like you do not have an executable file named `dir`.